# Regex for limiting characters

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex in which -

1. No lowercase letters
2. No leading or trailing whitespace
3. Length should be less than or equal to 18

I tried

```
^[^\s][A-Z0-9\W]{0,18}
```

Comment: For which cases is your regex failing and why do you think that is the case? Also: does "No lowercase letters" mean that any character aside from lowercase letters are allowed? What is allowed?

Comment: Every character including special characters are allowed. For ex- 'AD12&  @#()/@&6' is allowed (no leading and trailing whitespace)

Comment: Good answers already, for [unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) support consider e.g. [`^(?!\s)\P{Ll}{0,17}[^\p{Ll}\s]$`](https://regex101.com/r/0tZPSI/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\A(?!\s)[^a-z]{0,18}\z(?<!\s)
```

In Java, you can define it as

```java
bool valid = text.matches("\\A(?!\\s)[^a-z]{0,18}\\z(?<!\\s)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6kcpu/1) (adapted for testing against a single multiline text).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?!\s)` - no whitespace allowed right after
- `[^a-z]{0,18}`  - zero to eighteen occurrences of any chars other than lowercase ASCII letters (replace `[^a-z]` with `\P{Ll}` to match any chars other than Unicode lowercase letters)
- `\z(?<!\s)` - end of string that has no whitespace immediately before it.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the match with a non whitespace char other than a-z

Then optionally match 0-16 chars other than a lowercase char followed by again a non whitespace char other than a-z.

```
^[^\sa-z](?:[^a-z\r\n]{0,16}[^\sa-z])?$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^[^\\sa-z](?:[^a-z\\r\\n]{0,16}[^\\sa-z])?$";
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\sa-z]` Match a non whitespace char other than a-z
- `(?:` Non capture grup

  - `[^a-z\r\n]{0,16}` Match 0-16 chars other than a-z or a newline
  - `[^\sa-z]` Match a non whitespace char other than a-z
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional to also match a single character
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kGYQM/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/P5ASeD)

Comment: It does not match empty string.

Comment: @英語は苦手 Why should it match an empty string? The pattern of the OP also starts with `[^\s]` which matches a non whitespace char.

Comment: Don't ask me.  An empty string conforms to three criteria.

Comment: @英語は苦手 Well, then you can make the whole pattern optional `^(?:[^\sa-z](?:[^a-z\r\n]{0,16}[^\sa-z])?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/Rg9zzl/1